# Is my HVAC compressor siezed?

Tags: hvac, air-conditioning, electric-motor, compressor

My R22 HVAC system stopped working. Trying to see if there is anything else I can do

When the compressor kicks on I hear a buzzing sound (presumably when the capacitor is in start mode) and a hen goes run mode.

Things I have checked:

1. Gauges show around 130PSI on the high and low sides. No pressure seems to come from the compressor.
2. Checked the contactor and confirmed it is working. The resistance is 0 ohms when pushed in and infinity when pushed out. 240 volts from both phases get to both sides of the contactor when it is engaged.
3. Tested dual capacitor and it tested properly. I went to an HVAC supply store and replaced it anyway. No luck. I also bought a hard start kit and that didn't help start it either.
4. I checked the compressor leads. There is continuity between Start \ Run, Common \ Run, and Common \ Start
5. There is resistance on all the winding wires.

Start \ Run 2.7 ohm
Common \ Start 1.85 ohm
Common \ Run 0.8 ohm

Is this a siezed compressor? Is there anything else I can try?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you have a clamp meter you can check the current draw of the compressor.

A too high current indicates either a stalled compressor or the compressor spinning freely not doing any compressing.

It is also possible that an internal part of the compressor failed which would also need replacement of the compressor.

Replacing a compressor requires both specialized equipment and in most territories a license to work on refrigerant systems. Especially when it's a on a system with a refrigerant that is being phased out.

Comment: Actually, if spinning freely, you'd see lower amp draw than the name plate rating.

Comment: I went to the store and bought a clamp meter. The start yellow wire was drawing about 6 Amps. The red run wire and common wire were drawing 96 Amps. The side of the units says 96 LRA, so I am assuming this means the rotor is locked. The unit is from 1998 so I don't think replacing the compressor makes sense since the evaporator and condenser coils are probably close to failure and the lines might have metal contamination from motor damage.